# Hyper-V on libvirt

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, hyper-v, libvirt

I need to setup Windows 8.1 VM on my libvirt server to develop a Windows 8 phone application..

To do that I need to setup the VM CPU to support Hyper-V technologie, I can't find it in the CPU feature list..

Can you guide me to find what feature to activate?

Answer (score 0):

Plz Make sure that You are using a Windos 8.1 Professional with 4 Gb Ram. If You are using the Same then remove all the antivirus sequirty form your System.

aftr doing that go to windows Properties and unable the Hyper-V option.

I think Wll help you to sove your issue..